# Plotting Categorical Variable (x) against Continuous Variable (y) in R

Tags: r, graph, categorical-data

Would anybody please be able to help with the R code needed to plot my data?  I have been trying for hours and searching all over the web, I am really struggling.

This is an example of my data placed into a table/matrix, in R Studio:

```
      Percentage Correct
4     71.88
20    65.80
40    63.92
60    63.47
```

The `4`,`20`,`40`and`60` are categorical variables - they represent different levels of categorical interference.

`Percentage Correct` is the percentage of images that participants got correct for each interference level.

So for example, `63.47` means that when the interference category was 60, the average percentage of correct responses across all participants was 63.47%.

Below I have attached a couple of images of graphs that I am trying to achieve. I don't necessarily want mine to be that complex, but just like the basic style.

I am struggling to actually plot anything at all at the minute without getting any errors.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, thank you very much!

[image: Example Graph 1]

[image: Example Graph 2]

Comment: It looks like you have a data frame with one column and you categorical variable in row names? If so, the first thing you should do it convert those row names to a column of class `factor` (which is used for categorical data). Something like `your_data$category = factor(row.names(your_data), levels = row.names(your_data))`. The `levels = ` is necessary to keep them in the order they appear, not alphabetical order.

Comment: It would be really nice if you'd share a copy/pastable version of your input, `dput(your_data)` is perfect for being copy/paste-able and including all the class and structure information.

Comment: @Gregor hi, yes that's correct about my current data frame. I tried doing  `subset_correct_new$interfere = factor(row.names(subset_correct_new), levels = row.names(subset_correct_new))` but this has changed the `intefere` coloumn in my dataset from `4` `20` `40` `60` to the numbers 1 to 500 odd?

Comment: I can't replicate that on sample data I threw together. Can you please share your data with `dput()` to clear up any confusion?

Comment: @Gregor I tried using `dput()`, but the subset that I have done this particular analysis on and generated the numbers to put into the table that is in my original post, is huge. I can't paste the entire output into this comments box.

Comment: Just do a sample. `dput(your_data[1:6, "Percentage Correct", drop = FALSE])` should give the first 6 rows of the Percentage Correct column. If it's still to big, then you must have another factor in there, so use `dput(droplevels(...))` to get rid of the factor levels that aren't present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible start using `ggplot2`:

```
# Your sample data
df <- read.table(text =
    "x y
4     71.88
20    65.80
40    63.92
60    63.47", header = T);

library(ggplot2);
ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(x), y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    labs(y = "Percentage correct", x = "Categorical variable");
```

[image]

If you turn `x` into a `factor` it will be treated as a categorical variable.

---

Or as a barchart (as suggested by @neilfws):

```
library(ggplot2);
ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(x), y)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    labs(y = "Percentage correct", x = "Categorical variable");
```

[image]

Comment: @neilfws Thanks & good suggestion! I've added a barchart example.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Very helpful. I'm currently trying to turn the x variable into a factor, using the code given to me in a comment above. But I'm really struggling, I am quite a novice when it comes to R!

Comment: @EdinPC Turning a `character`/`numeric` vector into a `factor` should be as simple as `as.factor(...)`. E.g. `x <- c(4, 20, 40); x_as_factor <- as.factor(x);`. That's exactly what I do in the call to `ggplot`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers ah okay, thank you very much. I think I have done what you mean. Is this correct? `x <- c(4, 20, 40, 60);
x_as_factor <- as.factor(x);
y <- c(correct_int_4_per, correct_int_20_per, correct_int_40_per, correct_int_60_per);
ggplot(????)` I'm just not sure how I now get that x (as factor) variable and y variable that I have made into the `ggplot()` function

Comment: @EdinPC Look at my example! `ggplot` requires a `data.frame` (`df` in my example), from which you select an "x" (`as.factor(x)`) and "y" (`y`) column.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I'm really sorry for being an absolute novice but I am still confused. I understand that `ggplots()` requires a data frame, and you have made one in your example called `df`. But, in your example you read the table as text. Now that I have created an x variable and y variable, with actual variable values, not just numbers - how would I put that into a data frame?

Comment: @EdinPC you can ignore the `read.table` bit - that's just Maurits showing how he imported the data you shared (since you didn't use `dput` or similar...). You can skip that bit and use whatever you data frame is called wherever this answer uses `df`. But you'll also need to get your categorical variable as a column if it is currently row.names.

Comment: @EdinPC To add to @Gregor's comment, if you have two `numeric` vectors `x` and `y`, you can do `ggplot(data.frame(x = x, y = y), aes(as.factor(x), y)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")` to create a `data.frame` "on the fly" and plot a barplot.

Comment: @EdinPC If this answers your question please close the question by setting the check mark next to the answer.